# Bash: making my own shell

Tags: bash, shell, command-prompt

I am making a shell that resembles Command Prompt (it is not finished) but it doesn't work. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
VER=$(lsb_release -sr)
OS=$(lsb_release -si)
echo "Linux [Distro $OS Version $VER]"
echo "<c> None"
echo -n "${PWD}>"
read $cmd
eval $cmd
```

I am running on Crunchbang.
When I run it:

```
crunchbang@crunchbang:~$ ./cmd.sh
Linux [Distro Debian Version 7.0]
/home/crunchbang>echo "abc"    
crunchbang@crunchbang:~$
```

What it should be:

```
crunchbang@crunchbang:~$ ./cmd.sh
Linux [Distro Debian Version 7.0]
/home/crunchbang>echo "abc"
abc
crunchbang@crunchbang:~$
```

Even better:

```
crunchbang@crunchbang:~$ ./cmd.sh
Linux [Distro Crunchbang Version 11]
/home/crunchbang>echo "abc"
abc
crunchbang@crunchbang:~$
```

Comment: That's clearly not the output from the code snippet you gave us as the output from `echo "<c> None"` is not there in any of your versions.

Comment: I don't know why. I posted this a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read $cmd` is incorrect. You meant `read cmd`.

You only use `$` to reference a variable, not name one.

Your input is likely ending up in `$REPLY`.

Comment: +1 If `cmd` doesn't have a previous value, `$cmd` expands to the empty string, `read` doesn't get an optional argument, and `REPLY` is used. If `cmd` *has* a value, say `foo`, then `read $cmd` would set the value of the variable `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the $ off the read line

`read cmd`

Bash is expanding the variable to nothing, and executing "read"